# OpenGL 4+ will not work on RemoteFX with Windows Server 2012 Standard host and Windows 7 SP1 Enterprise/Windows 8.1 Enterprise VMs

Tags: windows-7, hyper-v-server-2012, windows-8.1, opengl, remote-desktop

I have installed Windows Server 2012 Standard on the following hardware:

-Intel desktop motherboard with Virtualization hardware support.
-16 GB of RAM
-Intel i5-2500 (Supports SLAT)
-nVidia Quadro 5000
-1TB HDD

As per **http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/16652.remotefx-vgpu-setup-and-configuration-guide-for-windows-server-2012.aspx** I have setup HyperV and the Remote Desktop Virtualization Host Role with the appropriate features.

I installed the latest video drivers from the nVidia site, the "QUADRO/NVS/TESLA/GRID DESKTOP DRIVER RELEASE 331" package. I configured HyperV to use the Quadro card for RemoteFX. I confirmed that dxdiag on the host server shows WDDM 1.2 and DirectX 11.

I built 2 guest machines normally, one with Windows 7 Enterprise SP1, one with Windows 8.1 Enterprise Evaluation. On both guest machines I installed all updates available, added the local users to the Remote Desktop Users group from the Local Users and Groups UI, and then shut down each. I snapshot'ed each, and then added the RemoteFX 3D Video Adapter card to their configurations.

When I boot the Win7 VM, I am able to connect from another Windows 7 SP1 box via "LAN" quality RDP and see that the RemoteFX capabilities are in use, but dxdiag and Device Manager only show that the system is using DirectX 9.0c and OpenGL1.1 capabilities, with WDDM 1.0 shown.

When I boot the Win8.1 VM, I am able to connect from the same Windows 7 SP1 box via "LAN" quality RDP, but the RemoteFX Graphics device is stopped showing a Code 43 error in Device Manager. DirectX diagnostics show "RDPUDD Chained DD" as the device. The troubleshooter doesn't solve the problem.

What I need to know is:
-Is there a missing step to get OpenGL 1.1-4+ working through RemoteFX?
-How can I get Windows 8.1 to properly install and use the RemoteFX device?
-As I am not using any baseboard management controller, would the cap driver gain me anything?

I did some reading and there is some kind of RemoteFX Cap Driver, but I don't really understand what it does and have not installed it as of yet.

Answer (score 3):

Further research shows that OpenGL higher than 1.1/1.2 is not supported. Microsoft chose to support primarily DirectX.

Windows 8.1 will not work with RemoteFX at this time. Windows 8 will.

The cap driver is not needed to get it to function.